# React-Hooks: Can't enable Input after it being disabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to control if my points input is enabled or disabled. When I click on checked, it disabled as expected. When I uncheck it remains disabled. I first tried setting `disabled={isChecked}` then I created it's own state I'd toggle using `useEffect` neither work. Once it's disabled, it won't toggle back to enabled.

```
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

  const handleChecked = event => {
    handleChange(event);
    setIsChecked(checked => !checked);
    setFieldValue(`questionData.${idx}.answers.${answer}.point`, 0);
    setFieldTouched(event.target.name);
  };



    <FormControlLabel
        control={
          <Checkbox
            name={`field1`}
            onChange={handleChecked}
            value={isChecked}
          />
        }
        label="Disable points"
        style={{ marginTop: 15, marginLeft: 8 }}
    />
    <FastField
      as={InputField}
      name={`field2`}
      label="Points"
      type="number"
      inputProps={{ min: '0', max: '100', step: '1' }}
      disabled={isChecked}
      handleError={handleError}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `checked` prop to your `Checkbox`

```js
<FormControlLabel
  control={
    <Checkbox
      checked={isChecked}
      name={`field1`}
      onChange={handleChecked}
      value={isChecked}
    />
  }
  label="Disable points"
  style={{ marginTop: 15, marginLeft: 8 }}
/>
```

Comment: I added it. But the checkbox works fine. The isn't is the input next to it. When the checkbox is checked the input should be disabled, when the checkbox is unchecked the input should be enabled. Right now when it's disabled, it won't go back to enable.

Comment: Can you change your handler to use the second argument that `onChange` gives you? Checkbox provides a `checked`. `const handleChecked = (event, checked) => { setChecked(checked) }`.

Comment: It still won't uncheck :/

Comment: Strange, I replaced Formiks FastField with Field and it's working? Seems like it's a Formik related issue I'm experiencing.